# distribution of an angle between random points

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, uniform-distribution

Let X, Y two random (uniform) points from the circle $x^{2} + y^{2} = 1$. What if the distribution of an angle between these points?

My try: To generate the point X from the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ is the same, that generate angle $\theta_{X} \sim $ Uniform[$0, 2\pi$] and than taking $X = (\cos \theta_{X}, \sin \theta_{X})$. Than angle between X and Y is $max(\theta_{X}, \theta_{Y}) - \min(\theta_{X}, \theta_{Y})$

Comment: Note that regardless of what point $X$ you choose, you can rotate the entire circle to re-orient it at an angle of $0$.

Comment: Do you mean, that the angle will be Uniform[0, $\pi$] though? If so, what about the case, when $\theta_{X}$ has some nonuniform distribution on the surface of circle?

Comment: For any general distributions, I imagine you would need to use convolution of the random variables.

Comment: yeah, but how exactly? Imagine we have $p_{\theta}(x) = a \cdot x + b, x \in [0, 2 \pi] $ - pdf of angle $\theta$. How to compute distribution of angle between 2 random points

Comment: What do you mean by the "angle between two points." By definition, an angle needs three points to make sense...

Comment: The two points are x and y (those on the circle) and the third is point (0, 0) - middle of the circle